# CEF ( Chromium Embedded Framework) user_agent bug？c++

Tags: c++, user-agent, chromium, chromium-embedded

My code is for example:

```
// Returns the application settings based on command line arguments.
void AppGetSettings(CefSettings& settings) {
  ASSERT(g_command_line.get());
if (!g_command_line.get())
   return;
  CefString str;
#if defined(OS_WIN)
  settings.multi_threaded_message_loop =
      g_command_line->HasSwitch(cefclient::kMultiThreadedMessageLoop);
#endif

CefString(&settings.locale).FromASCII("zh-cn");
  SystemSetting ss;

  CefString(&settings.cache_path) = L"cache";
  // Specify a port to enable DevTools if one isn't already specified.
  if (!g_command_line->HasSwitch("remote-debugging-port"))
     settings.remote_debugging_port = 8088;

std::wstring wversion = ss.ReadConfigSection(L"version", L"currentVersion");
  std::string version;
  CommonUtil::WStringToString(wversion, version);
  std::string tempStr = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.138 Safari/537.36 testuser_agent/";
  tempStr = tempStr.append(version);
  CefString(&settings.user_agent).FromString(tempStr);

  std::wstring logSeverity = ss.ReadConfigSection(L"config", L"logSeverity");
  if (!logSeverity.empty())
  {
     if (logSeverity == L"LOGSEVERITY_DEFAULT")
        settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_DEFAULT;
     else if (logSeverity == L"LOGSEVERITY_VERBOSE")
        settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_VERBOSE;
     else if (logSeverity == L"LOGSEVERITY_INFO")
        settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_INFO;
     else if (logSeverity == L"LOGSEVERITY_WARNING")
        settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_WARNING;
     else if (logSeverity == L"LOGSEVERITY_ERROR")
        settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_ERROR;
     else if (logSeverity == L"LOGSEVERITY_DISABLE")
        settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_DISABLE;
  }
  else
     settings.log_severity = cef_log_severity_t::LOGSEVERITY_DISABLE;

  if (g_command_line->HasSwitch(cefclient::kOffScreenRenderingEnabled))
    settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = true;
}
```

but is in

```
 #define CHROME_VERSION_MAJOR 35
```

is fail,but other vesion is  succeed,this is a bug for CEF?
    CefString(&settings.user_agent).FromString(tempStr);
this is succeed in other version,Is is my error?but why only this one is fail?And I is look for a lot of material,but is not help ?Who can help me,thanks very much!